# How to use createMicroservice factory in a AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs

I'm using NestJS to create a microservice, hosted on AWS Lambda.

lambda.ts:

```
let cachedApp: INestApplicationContext;

async function bootstrap(): Promise<INestApplicationContext> {
    if (!cachedApp) {
        cachedApp = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule);
        cachedApp.init();
        // cachedApp.listen() is a NO GO since we're in a serverless lambda! 
    }
    return cachedApp;
}

export const sqsHandler = async (event, context: Context) => {    
    const instance = await bootstrap();    
    // How can I parse the 'event' to the instance??
};
```

The function `sqsHandler` is triggered every time an event is push to a SQS queue.

How can I parse the lambda event to the nestjs microservice instance and get the result?

Lots of examples online shows how to use the `NestFactory.createMicroservice` with `listen()`, this is not a solution since this code is executed in a serverless AWS Lambda.

Also, using a stand-alone nestjs app is also not an option, since we need to implement a custom transport strategy.